# Perl writing from socket to a file

Tags: perl, sockets

Another issue with perl script. This script creates socket,accept incoming connection and save data from socket to a file. I use netcat:

```
netcat 127.0.0.1 6000 <my_data.txt
```

But maybe I will be forced to write a perl script with client :/ Is it possible?

Is this method done properly? When I execute the scipt i have :
"Can't use string ("my_data.txt") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at  "
The error indicate on  `print $my_data "$data\n";`

EDIT: Full code included
My whole loop is here:

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use IO::Socket;
use JSON;

my $local_host;
my $local_port;
my $save_dir;
my $my_data;
#HELP
#sudo cpanm install JSON


sub config {
my $filename = 'perl_config.txt';
my $json_text = do {
    open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename)
        or die("Nie moge otworzyc pliku!");
    local $/;
    <$json_fh>
};
my $json = JSON->new;

my $data = $json->decode($json_text);



$local_host=$data->{'local_host'};
$local_port=$data->{'local_port'};
$save_dir=$data->{'save_dir'};
$my_data=$data->{'my_data'};

#Tworzymy folder, jesli on nie istnieje!
if (! (-d $save_dir)) {
mkdir($save_dir,0755) ;
print "Folder do zapisu zostal stworzony pod nazwa: $save_dir\n" ;
  }


};


config();

my $my_socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
LocalHost => $local_host,
LocalPort => $local_port,
Proto     => 'tcp',
Listen    => 5,
Reuse     => 1
);
die "Nie udalo sie stworzyc socketu: my_socket $!n " unless $my_socket;
print "Mozesz juz wysylac dane z klienta \n";
my $accepter = $my_socket->accept();
open(DATA, ">$my_data");
while(<$accepter>){
#print $_;
#next;

my $data = <$my_socket>;
print $my_data "$data\n";

}



close(DATA);
close($my_socket);
```

Comment: First please always `use strict` since you can catch some errors here already, like `$my_data` not defined (should be `DATA`?). Also, you cannot read from the listener socket `$my_socket` as you do with `my $data = <$my_socket>;`. This likely should be reading from `$accepter`. But you already do the latter one although you ignore the result from this.

Comment: I use strict:
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use IO::Socket;
use JSON;

Comment: If you would do this with the code you show you would get `Global symbol "$my_data" requires explicit package name`. Or you don't show the full code.

Comment: I don't show full code. I will edit my post in a sec. Give me a moment sir ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$my_data=$data->{'my_data'};
...
open(DATA, ">$my_data");
...
print $my_data "$data\n";
```

This should likely be `print DATA "$data\n";` in the last line since you want to write to the opened file handle.

Comment: Now i have this error:
Use of uninitialized value $data in concatenation (.) or string at ./proj_perl.pl line 62.

Comment: @patrykoz: Your original question was answered. As for the new problem you better ask a new question since  questions should not be a moving target. But as a hint of what the problem is I cite from my first comment: *"you cannot read from the listener socket $my_socket as you do with my $data = <$my_socket>;. This likely should be reading from $accepter. But you already do the latter one although you ignore the result from this. "*.

Comment: But I also asked if my method was done properly. I have to write this script, but Perl is not my world. It has odd syntax.

Comment: @patrykoz: So did you understand my hint? Note that it would be really useful if your code contained any documentation of what you are attempting since in this case one could match what you are actually doing with what you are really doing and point out the errors.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why OP stores configuration in JSON file.

Please investigate the following code sample which uses Config::General module to read configuration file.

Point your web browser to [http://localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080/) and read some html header data in `socket_data.txt` file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use IO::Socket;
use Config::General;

my $fname = 'socket_data.txt';
my $cfile = 'network.cnf';
my $count = 0;

my $conf   = Config::General->new($cfile);
my %config = $conf->getall;

$| = 1;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
    LocalHost => $config{host},
    LocalPort => $config{port},
    Proto     => $config{proto},
    Listen    => 5,
    Reuse     => 1
);

die "ERROR: can not open socket $!" unless $socket;

say 'Waiting for incoming data';

my $socket_handle = $socket->accept();

open my $fh, '>', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname";

while( <$socket_handle> ) {
    chomp;
    last if $count++ == 10;
    say;
    say $fh $_;
}

close $fh;
close $socket_handle;
```

Config file `network.cnf`

```
host  = 127.0.0.1
port  = 8080
proto = tcp
```

Output sample

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
```

Comment: Honestly? It's the simplest project I've invented which has few features like:sockets, use files and directories (operations), read sth from json. I do it as a "weekendly" project for subject on university... It not depends on me :/

Comment: You free to choose JSON to store configuration but it involves more effort to maintain JSON file (you previously came across this problem -- not balanced `,` or use `'` instead `"` for example). Personally for me it is not clear why JSON was chosen to store configuration -- although I do not exclude that you can have your reason to do so.